# Select row owner in oracle table

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table named Table1, and I have five users with SELECT and INSERT privileges, each one of these users had populated data to the table.
How to display each row is owner ? for example row 1 inserted by user2, row 2 inserted by user4 and so on?

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to find out which user added existing rows.  To know for future inserted rows, add this column to the table:

```
alter table table1 add created_by varchar2(30) default user;
```

Another commonly added column is:

```
alter table table1 add created_date date default sysdate;
```

Comment: Will this populate the user who inserts the record or the user who created the table ?

Comment: @KaushikNayak Who inserted the row

Comment: Thanks.. don't know why was I confused about it for a moment.

Comment: On **existing** rows, the `alter table` statement will set the new `created_by` column to the user who issued the `alter table`.

Comment: your alter will modify the table by adding new column

Comment: Since we could know who create the table, is there any way also to know who inserted the row?

Comment: @D.Maria yes, see my answer!

Comment: @Tony Andrews your answer will alter the table, will add new column, I do not want to modify the table by adding new columns

Comment: @D.Maria In that case you can't know who inserted which row, sorry!